# Getting the error already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I know It's a repeated question but I tried to add MARS `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` in my connection string and it didn't work and still getting the same issue. I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v17.5.

Here's my connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Server=myserver;Database=mydb;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"  
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What could be the issue which preventing MARS from getting activated?

```
public SqlListener()
{
    ConnectionString = "DefaultConnection";
    connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionString].ConnectionString;

    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;

    sqlCmd.Connection.Open();
    SqlDependency.Start(connString);
}

public void executeSQLCMD(string queryType, string queryTxt)
{
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = queryTxt;

    SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

and then another switch with multiple data readers

```
switch (queryType)
{
    case "SelectAHTQ":
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "SP_1";

                // fails here--> SqlDataReader AHTReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (AHTReader.Read())
                {
                    LiveAHTDetails details = new LiveAHTDetails();
                    details.AHT = AHTReader.GetDouble(0);
                    details.ccName = AHTReader.GetString(1);
                    details.connectionID = connectionId;
                    this.liveStatus.liveDetails.Add(details);
                }
                break;
      .....
```

Thanks

Comment: You also need to share the code which gives you this error.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're encountering the error on? (as an aside, 17.5 will be the version of Sql Server Management Studio that you're using, not the SQL Server database you're connecting to, which can be found by running `SELECT @@Version`)

Comment: SQL Server version is 2012 @Diado.

Comment: I read the title 5 times and still did not understand. Could you state it better please?

Comment: "already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first" is an error which I'm getting when I try to use multiple datareader

Answer (score 1):

You must close the DataReader object before executing another SQL statement.

Comment: I want to avoid opening and closing connection multiple times especially in my case as I'm using a high server demand queries

Comment: Connection pooling will stop that being an issue. Just close the DataReader.